# How do I re-index filtered divs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, indexing, visibility

I have a filter function that uses div classes by finding the class and hiding everything else. I also have a function that dynamically adds a div, but it's not working correctly with the filter function. The dynamically added div is added to the end of each row using the index number.

**The problem is that the hidden divs retain their original index number. I'd like to detach them all (keep the contents of the div) and add them after the selected divs.**

```
Example before filtering (A0 = filter/index):
A0  B1  A2
<Dynamic Div after Row 1>
A3  B4  B5

This is what happens now when I filter:
B1  B4  B5
A0  A2  A3
<Dynamic Div after Row 1 - because A2 is the end of row 1 according to the index>

This is what I need to happen:
B0  B1  B2
<Dynamic Div after Row 1 - index numbers were changed>
A3  A4  A5
```

This is my filtering function:

```
$('nav a').click(function(){
    var content = '.content';
    var portfolio = '#portfolio > a';
    var getClass = $(this).attr('class'); //get the filter via class

    //hides any active content windows
    if($(content).length) { $(content).slideUp(300, function(){ $(this).remove(); }); }

    if(getClass){
        $('.tags').not("." + getClass).slideUp(300, function() {     //hide all tags except selected tag
            $("." + getClass).slideDown(300);   //show selected tag if already hidden
            $(portfolio).children($('.tags').not("." + getClass).parent()).detach();
        });
    } else {
        $('.tags').slideDown(300); //show all
    }

});
```

This is the line I'm not getting right:

```
$(portfolio).children($('.tags').not("." + getClass).parent()).detach();
```

I need to select the .tags inside portfolio so I don't remove navigation elements, but I need to select the anchor-link (parent element) of that div.

Stackoverflow won't let me post an image of my elements, and I can't get the html code to look right, but essentially my elements look like:
`a href="content.php"`
`div class="tags branding" style="background:url(images/BacktoSchool-header.jpg)"`
`div class="text"`
`Content Name`

Comment: Why exactly do you want to detach elements instead of just hiding them? I feel like that is making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @tcovo when they're hidden they retain their index numbers. Right now the dynamic div is inserted in the right place when all the elements are visible, but when things are filtered out it's placed where it would go according to the index number regardless of its visibility. From a UX standpoint, that's the wrong place. I need to insert it after the third column of the visible element, but the element in that column could be any number. I thought reindexing the divs would be easier than figuring out a function to determine the index of the element in third column.

Comment: I don't think it would be that hard to insert the dynamic div at a certain index within the _visible_ columns. Something like this: `$dynamicElement.insertBefore($('.column').filter(':visible').eq(index))` (this needs extra code to handle case where there are no visible columns). If you provide your code which inserts the dynamic div, I could give more specific code.

Comment: I've figured it out, but can't answer for 6 hours...

Comment: @tcovo thanks for your help. This is my working code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cQUMs/7/) The dynamic divs don't work properly on jsfiddle because there's no content links, but they work correctly while I'm testing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a line in my navigation making the name attribute hold the class value so that I could hide all the `'.tags'` without removing the navigation elements or needing to target the portfolio's children's class, then the class's parent.

Changes in working code are:

```
var getClass = $(this).attr('name'); //get the filter via name

if(getClass){
    $('.tags').not("." + getClass).slideUp(300, function() {     //hide all tags except selected tag
        $("." + getClass).slideDown(300);   //show selected tag if already hidden
            $holder = $('.tags').not("." + getClass).parent().detach();  //detaches all the other tags
            $holder.insertAfter($(portfolio + ':last'))  //appends them
        });
    } else {
        $('.tags').slideDown(300); //show all
    }
```